# localhost loading wrong css files

Tags: php, apache

I have a custom website in Magento 1.9 running on my localhost, its Ubuntu 18. LTS , running on a php 5.6 and apache, everything works fine, but not the css

This is the url is loading:

```
http://local.mysite.com/var/www/html/mysite/skin/frontend/base/default/css/files.css
```

So as you can see it loads /var/www/html witch is wrong, this is my virtual hosts inside apache2 folder sites-available:

local.mysite.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain1.com
  ServerName  local.mysite.com
  ServerAlias local.mysite.com


  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite


  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-mysite.com.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-mysite.com.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Just for the record i have enabled mod rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: can we see your head element?

Comment: not sure what you mean, its a Magento site.

Comment: can we see how you add the css file? also what magento version?

Comment: Sounds like you have a Magento setting set to /var/www/html/mysite - when it should probably be just '/'

Answer (score 0):

Guys you can try this to solve the problem. I also faced the same problem it helped me

i redid all the steps that i have done before, like getting all the files from svn, re-importing the database, and changing the web/unsecure/base_url & web/secure/base_url, configuring apache virtual hosts etc..

but i think what solved the problem was changing the ownership of media and var directories to www-data instead of `user` and giving those folders full permissions.

I have done this step because in the main server, the those directories were owned by www-data user..

Also, i observed that the css was loading from zz.com/media/css folder, which was automatically created once the media directory was setup properly, which did not happen earlier, the directory has css files like 0a039da6028e6d636132ecd5e235f417.css etc..

the request url was something like this (from net window in firebug)...

```
http://zz.com/media/css/0a039da6028e6d636132ecd5e235f417.css
```

and not like the one i mentioned how it should be above (`http://zz.com/skin/frontend/default/jm_wall/css/layout.css`), nor like how the request was sent (`http://zz.com/var/www/zz.com/skin/frontend/default/jm_wall/css/layout.css`)

Hope this helps someone else...